# How to I append text to jQuery selection?

Tags: jquery

Given this HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"><span>Apple</span>
<input type="checkbox"><span>Orange</span>
<input type="checkbox"><span>Lemon</span>
```

and this jQuery

```
var checked_items = jQuery("input:checked").next().text();
console.log(checked_items);
```

I get this result

AppleOrangeLemon

How can I insert separators? So that I get **Apple, Orange, Lemon** 
This doesn't work:

```
var checked_items = jQuery("input:checked").next().text().append(", ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
var names = $('span').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/6j3tfwrs/)

The [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method applies a function to each item in an array or object and maps the results into a new array.

I have given `span` as a selector just to show an example. You can use appropriate selector instead of that.

Comment: Where do the commas come from?

Comment: When you convert an array to a string, it does it as if you'd done `array.join(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you. It adds a comma and a space.

https://jsfiddle.net/qccxoogx/1/

```
$("<span>,&nbsp;</span>").insertBefore($("input:checkbox:not(:first)"));
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  The result you want is without the checkboxes? The result of my example is Apple, Orange, Lemon with the checkboxes.